# spark could not find spark-class-launcher-output file when given --driver-class-path

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I'm trying to get spark to play nice with aws.  Working in a windows environment.

The NativeS3 classes are never found regardless of the options that I've tried.  Currently if I use : `spark-shell --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.10.38,com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.10.38,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1` as my command then I will dwnload the files and can use s3 however tha feels hacky and downloading them every tie is not ideal.

With the help of another I've been trying other options which lead to :

```
>spark-shell --driver-class-path=C:\Spark\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar;C:\Spark\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar" --verbose
```

there was an error with copying the file that didn't exist, I changed the path of temp just to cover privilege doubt but this error remains:

```
   C:\java_1.7\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java -cp "C:\Spark\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar;C:\Spark\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar --verbose > c:\temp\spark-class-launcher-output-4879.txt;C:\Spark\bin\..\conf
Xms1g -Xmx1g "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --conf "spark.driver.extraClassPath=C:\Spark\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\hadoop-aws-2.7.1.jar;C:\Spark\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar --verbo
The system cannot find the file c:\temp\spark-class-launcher-output-4879.txt.
Could Not Find c:\temp\spark-class-launcher-output-4879.txt
```

it's been pinpointed to this particular line in the `spark-class2.cmd` file but I do not know how to solve it.

```
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/bin/spark-class2.cmd#L59
```

Can anyone shed any light at all?  Thank you in advance

Comment: could you try with setting the master to something like , for example `>spark-shell --master local[*] ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

one thing that caught my eye was the drive letter in the error

c:\temp\spark-class-launcher-output-4879.txt.

It is smaller case.
Checking the code for spark-class2.cmd indicates that it reads out %temp% variable.

Can you run `echo %temp%` in windows command line to see what is set?

If it is set to lowercase, then simply run `set temp=C:\temp`

Then run spark-shell with driver-class.

Thanks,

Charles.

Comment: Hey Charles, thanks for taking the time to answer.  I ended up manually updating the file locally and hardcoding the string for the path btu the same error remained. 

I then found that I coudl use the --jars flag instead, which now works, strangely enough.  I'm not adept to know if it's working correctly but the help for --driver--class-path implied that --jars would be added to path automaitcially - I'm now facing a closed port issue :(  Does this madness never end?

Answer (score 1):

I too had such issue for some good enough time. Later what I found was the issue with `JAVA_HOME` path misconfiguration.
Once I configured to definite path, the issue was resolved.

Also, try to follow the instructions mentioned in the link:
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html